# Right XPath syntax for getting nodelist of two types of elements by an ID

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML file with two types of elements, both have IDs. I would like to get a NodeList with the ones that have a specific ID.

```
    StringBuffer exp = new StringBuffer("//wert[@ID='");
    exp.append(elementId);
    exp.append("'] or //feld[@ID='");
    exp.append(elementId);
    exp.append("']");
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(exp.toString());
```

By doing this, however I get boolean as a return value. What would be the correct syntax, so that I could get a NodeList of the elements. Thanks!

Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the **union** operator, `|`. The XPath you build should look like

```
//wert[@Id='id']|//feld[@Id='id']
```